# Different autoOrients settings for universal Adobe Air iOS app

Tags: ios, air, screen-orientation

I'm working on an universal iPhone and iPad app with Adobe AIR (SDK 18).
I need to use`autoOrients` **false** (to keep the app in **portrait** mode) for the iPhone app but `autoOrients` **true** for the iPad version. Is there a way to do that?
This is from the app manifest:

```
<initialWindow>
    <content>example.swf</content>
    <aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
    <renderMode>gpu</renderMode>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
</initialWindow>
```